# Reading a large 2Gb file into with delimiter

Tags: java

I have a file which is 2 gb and more and i need to split it with an delimiter it an export of a db into flat file.

Each record separated by '\u0002\n'
and each field is separated by '\u0001'

```
FileChannel inChannel = new RandomAccessFile("apps", "r").getChannel();
MappedByteBuffer buffer = inChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0,
                                        inChannel.size());
```

The reading works but how can i split into each record ?

Comment: if it is a csv file use the opencsv library

Comment: If you need to process the whole file, you might not need `nio`. Read the file in chunks of a manageable size, and search for the delimiter in those chunks. Assuming you can buffer a single record in memory, if a chunk doesn't contain the delimiter, add it to the buffer - say, a `List<byte[]>`). If it does, add the part before the delimiter into the buffer, and process the buffer which now contains the whole record. You also might have to handle the delimiter being more than once in a chunk, which is a little tedious.

Comment: @Kathick Well it's fairly tedious and error prone code so you'd have to make do with something completely untested. You mention the separators are unicode characters - can I assume the file is UTF-8 text?